# How to style a button group dropdown?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have appearance of a group item just like this one http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split but I don't see a point for a label text to be styled as a button. What is the reason behind this, why not just make it a regular text? Especially since it doesn't trigger anything and this way I need to override all css values for it so it wont behave like a button.

What would be the cleanest way, with a least markup, to have a group button with text label and only a caret serving as a dropdown button?
Example [image]

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. What's the problem with bootstrap's buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first label button in the btn-group with this:

```
<span style="float:left;padding:6px 12px;">Rating</span>
```